# What is a order of firing postPersist, postRemove events in Doctrine2, when orphanRemoval is set to true?

Tags: php, events, doctrine-orm

I have entity `Order` witch has `@OneToOne` relation to second entity `File`, relation has `orphanRemoval` attribute set to `true`.

Now on `postRrmove` event, fired after removal of `File` entity I'm deleting related file form filesystem, on `postPersist` event I move uploaded file to destination location.

I'm wondering, when updating `Order` entity with new instance of `File` entity, what is an order of firing `postPersist` and `postRemove` events (in `orphanRemoval` context)?

Because if `postPersist` is fired first, nad new `File` instance has same filename as old one, the uploaded file will override old one, and `postRemove` event will delete it. Witch is unwanted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the first event fired is `postPersist` of new entity, and then `postRemove` of old entity.